# Inconsistency parsing data in Android. Offset TimeZone

Tags: android, parsing, date, calendar, timezone

I am developing an Android app which deals with dates from a lot of newspapers and deals with a lot of date formats. I am almost doing a very manual parsing but what is very surprising is that I don´t have the same results when I try the app on an ICS device that when I do so in a JB one. 
The parsing in question is happens when i construct an object that I have called new from some Strings parsed from XMls

```
 public class NewNew implements Parcelable, Comparable<NewNew>{

private String title;
private String link;
private String description;
private Date pubDate;
private String img;
private String country;

 public NewNew (String t, String l, String d, String f, String i, String c)
{
    this.title= t;
    this.link = l;
    this.description = d;

    //convert string to date
    Date date = toDate(f) ;
    this.pubDate= date;

    this.img=i;
    this.country=c;
}

 public Date toDate (String dateText)
{
Date d=null;
//Sat, 03 Aug 2013 17:06:30 +0000 that is the value of dateText
        SimpleDateFormat df5 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.getDefault());
d =  df5.parse(dateText.substring(5));
return d;
}
}
```

Very surprisingly it makes a Date object in ICS but not in JB device. I have tried to change devices configurations (Set timezone and time manually or automatically and it doesn´t make any difference)

Not sure if is relevant but ICS version is 4.0.4 and JB 4.3

---

I fixed that out by
Replacing Locale.getDefault() in the constructor of the SimpleDateFormat by a defined Locale, in my case Locale.US. It was not exactly what I wanted but once I have build the Date object I can print it setting manually the pattern in the SimpleDateFormat

```
TextView dateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, HH:mm");
dateTextView.setText(sdf.format(d);
```

Besides there was some parsing error on the format from XMLs pubDate. Even if you don´t see them writted if you debbug you notice that there were some dates with html /n or /t on them. I remove them by using the following code

```
 public String stripHtml(String html) {

     SpannableStringBuilder spannedStr = (SpannableStringBuilder) Html
                .fromHtml(html.trim());
        Object[] spannedObjects = spannedStr.getSpans(0, spannedStr.length(),
                Object.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < spannedObjects.length; i++) {
            if (spannedObjects[i] instanceof ImageSpan) {
                ImageSpan imageSpan = (ImageSpan) spannedObjects[i];
                spannedStr.replace(spannedStr.getSpanStart(imageSpan),
                        spannedStr.getSpanEnd(imageSpan), "");
            }
        }
        String textWeb = spannedStr.toString();
        return Html.fromHtml(textWeb).toString();

    }
```

I apply this method to the text parsed form XMLs before I try to parse it as a Date

Comment: You're defining a parameter `dateText` but do not reference it from within the method. Also, your parse method takes `fechaTexto.substring(5)` as an argument? Maybe you missed something when copy-pasting your code? If not, you should add the meaning of `fetchaTexto`.

Comment: You are right @dst, it was a mistake coping (and translating) the code. I corrected it and added some more code to clarify. Still it was a typo here but not in the source. Still having the same issue.

Comment: not making a Date object in JB means you get a `ParseException` as described in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29)? If so, post that one. If not, what happens?

Comment: @dst thanks a lot for your comments, I have edited the text with a solution that is currently working. It seems that ICS and JB have different implementation for the method Locale.getDefault(); Answering to your question I don´t get ParseException because my whole app goes around date so I have to control that possible error replacing null by a manually setted Date (a very old one) that is latter translated as "Non date available" when is writted to text. Thanks a lot for your help.